# Solitaire game where you deal four up, four down

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

What is the name of this solitaire game I learned when I was a kid?

You lay out 52 cards (1 deck), dealt four up, four down.

You get 8 piles:

- on the left, four face-up (arranged so you can see all of them).
- on the right, face downward except for the top card on each which is face-up.

This makes 7 cards per pile on the left and 6 per pile on the right.
To play, you stack cards on top of each other according to suit, in descending order (like jack of diamonds on queen of diamonds).
You move any cards on top along with the card you're placing on a higher one of the same suit.
Kings can go into empty spaces and aces go in a row above the cards you dealt out.
You must turn up all the face-down cards and you win if you get all 4 suits from ace to king in the piles above.

I have been searching the internet and nobody has mentioned a solitaire game laid out like this.

Comment: Are you able to explain how the cards are dealt out a little more? are there 1 / 4 / 8 piles?

Comment: Could you post a picture of a game in progress?

Comment: It sounds kind of like a mix between Freecell and Spider, does anything in [this video](https://youtu.be/lYJsDw6c-EY) look familiar?

Answer (score 4):

The game you are looking for is a mixture between the classic solitaire games Scorpion  and Yukon.

I've looked through over 700 games in both SolSuite Solitaire and Pretty Good Solitaire and I came really close to finding your game in a variation called Geoffrey (by Thomas Warfield) in Goodsol's game Pretty Good Solitaire. The only difference is that Geoffrey is played with the last 2 cards dealt face up (*instead of just the last card*) in the last 4 columns.

[image: Geoffrey from Pretty Good Solitaire]

Geoffrey
https://www.goodsol.com/games/geoffrey.html

Info
 - 1 Deck.
 - Success rate - Medium (30%).
 - Mostly Skill.

Layout
 - 4 Foundation columns (on top) - Build up in suit from Ace to King.
 - 8 Tableau columns (below foundation) - Build down in suit.
 - No Stock

Object of the game
To create four suites of 13 cards each in an ascending suit sequence from Ace to King, by moving all the cards from the tableau to the foundation.

Tableau
 - 52 cards in eight columns.
 - At the start of the game 7 cards are dealt to the first 4 columns and 6 cards are dealt to the next 4 columns.
 - In the first 4 columns, all cards are dealt face up. In the next 4 columns the first 4 cards are dealt face down and last 2 cards are dealt face up.

Rules
 - Tableau columns must be built down in suit, e.g. a 10 of ♠ can only be played on a Jack of ♠.
 - Any face up card, no matter how deep it is in a column, may be moved to make a build. All covering cards are moved with it together as a unit.
 - When a face down card is uncovered, it is automatically turned face up and is available for play.
 - Nothing can be placed on an Ace. A King cannot move, except to an empty space.
 - Spaces can only be filled with a King or groups of cards headed by a King.
 - Foundation columns must be built up in suit from Ace to King.
 - The top card of each tableau column is available for play to the foundations.
 - The game is won if the entire deck in all four suites has been moved to the foundation.

Here are some other examples of similar games:

Scorpion from SolSuite Solitaire 
[image: Scorpion by SolSuite Solitaire]

ScorpionCell from SolSuite Solitaire
[image]

Scorpion
https://www.politaire.com/scorpion

Applegate
https://www.politaire.com/applegate

Scorpion Head
https://www.politaire.com/scorpionhead

Three Blind Mice
https://www.politaire.com/threeblindmice

Farmers Wife
https://www.politaire.com/farmerswife

Double Scorpion
https://www.politaire.com/doublescorpion

Russian Solitaire
https://www.politaire.com/russian

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the game you are looking for is Scorpion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpion_(solitaire)